# How to aggregate (sum) values over month in jasperreports (each month should be the sum of all month before)

Tags: mysql, sql, jasper-reports, aggregate

I want to do a report with jasperreports that aggregates our contracts over the month but adding all new and old contracts to the month. The database is a mysql database.
My SELECT would look like this with example data below:

```
SELECT month(contract_date), amount
FROM contracts
WHERE year(contract_date)=2013
GROUP BY month(contract_date)

1.1.2013 300
1.1.2013 500
1.2.2013 250
1.3.2013 250
```

Now i get:

```
1 800
2 250
3 250
...
```

But i would like to have:

```
1 800
2 1050
3 1300
...
```

So each month contains the amount of all month before.

I dont mind if i can do this in SQL or with jasperreports/iReport, so any solution is welcome.
Is there any way i can do this?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't have CTEs which is inconvenient, but a view will do in a pinch.

```
create view MonthlyTotals as
    select  Month( ContractDate ) as ContractMonth, Sum( ContractQty ) as TotalQty
    from    contracts
    group by ContractMonth;
```

Now we can join the view with itself, maintaining a running total of the month and all previous months:

```
select  t1.ContractMonth, t1.TotalQty, Sum( t2.TotalQty ) as RunningTotal
from    MonthlyTotals t1
join    MonthlyTotals t2
  on    t2.ContractMonth <= t1.ContractMonth
group by t1.ContractMonth;
```

The output matches your desired output, as seen at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/126c8/5/0).

Comment: Thank you, thats nice. To do it without creating a view it seems like i can do it with an inline query:

    _select  t1.ContractMonth, t1.TotalQty, Sum( t2.ContractQty ) as RunningTotal

    from (select  Month( ContractDate ) as ContractMonth, Sum( ContractQty ) as TotalQty

      from    contracts

      group by ContractMonth) t1

    join    contracts t2 on month(t2.ContractDate) <= t1.ContractMonth
    
group by t1.ContractMonth;_